# Passing Data between Service and Controller Grails

Tags: grails, service, controller

I'm new on grails and I don't know how to solve this. I need to pass a data from a method in service class (someserviceclass.groovy) to an action controller in Grails. How can I do that?

Comment: The controller calls the service... Or it should do

Comment: No, I want that a service method call asynchronously an action in controller, passing a data to it.

Comment: That doesn't sound right... Think you'll need to explain your use case in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Controller

```
class MyController {
    def myService

    def myAction() {
        def values = myService.getData()

        [viewVarible: values]  // since our method return def we don't need to use return keyword
    }
 }
```

#### Service

```
class MyService {

    def getData() {
        def data = [:]

        data.put("key1", "value1")
        data.put("key2", "value2")
        data.put("key3", "value3")

        return data   // we could have just said data without the return keyword
    }
}
```